# converting 20130420151740.000000+120 to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

PowerShell Get-WMIObject returns DateTime fields as strings like this: `20130420151740.000000+120`

Type in a PowerShell the following command:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | select -Property InstallDate | Get-Member
```

You get a result like this:

```
TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                  
----        ----------   ----------                                  
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)              
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                           
GetType     Method       type GetType()                              
ToString    Method       string ToString()                           
InstallDate NoteProperty string InstallDate=20160331115110.000000+120
```

*In a C# program I need to convert these kind of strings*. What kind of format is this?? This looks like a `Double` plus an UTC offset in minutes. Usually this is displayed as `2013-04-20 15:17:40 +2:00`.

How can I transform it in C# to a C# type `DateTime`? Things like

```
string stringdate = "20160331115110.000000+120";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(stringdate);
```

or

```
string stringdate = "20160331115110.000000+120";
var date = DateTime.Parse(stringdate);
```

don't work. They throw a `System.FormatException exception` saying:

> Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @CodeCaster beat me to it...

Comment: @Priya don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) exactly for this format. You can call it like this:

```
using System.Management;
[...]
string stringdate = "20160331115110.000000+120";
DateTime dt = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(stringdate);
```

Comment: Didn't find and know about `ManagementDateTimeConverter` but it is exactly what I need and was looking for.

Comment: Glad, I could help you!

Comment: I wonder why I'm getting an hour offset with this. Is there a way to avoid this with this example?